# `apt --fix-broken` is broken (`uim` has circular dependencies)

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

## TL;DR

- `$ sudo apt upgrade` recommends I use `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`.
- `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install` is broken because `/var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-6_all.deb (--unpack)` fails.
- The `.deb` package fails because `/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm` does not exist.
- I can't fix `/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm` with `$ sudo apt upgrade` because `$ sudo apt upgrade` is broken.

## Full Question

I'm on Debian. My Wi-Fi went out right in the middle of a large `$ sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`. I don't know if that caused my problem, but since then I've been unable to `$ sudo apt upgrade`.

When I try to `$ sudo apt upgrade` I get the following error:

```
me@debian:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libuim-plugins : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim : Depends: uim-common (= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-anthy : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-fep : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-gtk2.0 : Depends: uim (= 1:1.8.8-6)
              Depends: uim-gtk2.0-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-6) but it is not installed
              Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6) but it is not installed
 uim-gtk3 : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-qt : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-qt5 : Depends: uim (= 1:1.8.8-6)
           Depends: uim-qt5-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-6) but it is not installed
           Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6) but it is not installed
 uim-utils : Depends: uim-common (>= 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) but it is not installed
 uim-xim : Depends: uim (>= 1:1.8.8-6)
           Depends: uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The `$ sudo apt autoremove` command gives a similar error and also recommends I run `$ apt --fix-broken install`

So, of course, I run `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

```
me@debian:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  uim uim-anthy uim-data uim-fep uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3 uim-gtk3-immodule uim-plugins uim-qt5-immodule
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libuim-plugins uim-qt uim-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  uim-data uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3-immodule uim-plugins uim-qt5-immodule
The following packages will be upgraded:
  uim uim-anthy uim-fep uim-gtk3
4 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 3 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,411 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,686 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of uim-anthy, which would be broken by installation of uim-data ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure uim-anthy (broken by uim-data)
(Reading database ... 338130 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-6_all.deb ...
De-configuring uim-anthy (1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2) ...
Error: in load: file "/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm" not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-6_all.deb (--unpack):
 installed uim-anthy package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-6_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As you can see, `apt` complains that the file `/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm` does not exist. This is true. The directory `/usr/share/uim/` does exist but it contains no `lib/` directory within it.

I don't know how to correct this because I'd normally fix it with `$ sudo apt upgrade`. But running `$ sudo apt upgrade` terminates with an error.

I tried searching for solutions elsewhere but [this](https://dwivedisurabhi7.blogspot.com/2012/10/solving-problem-of-browser-and-open.html) answer doesn't work and [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877918) suggests I might be in "[circular dependency hell](http://debian.2.n7.nabble.com/Bug-877918-uim-circular-dependency-hell-td4203184.html)". This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/74vpjz/debian_apt_upgrade_errors_regarding_uimdata_and/dogk5ht/) recommends I run `$ sudo apt dist-upgrade` but `dist-upgrade` is also broken by this issue.

I've tried uninstalling my `uim` libraries with `sudo apt remove <uim-package-name>` but this doesn't get ride of the unmet dependencies error.

It might be that the I should find a `sigscheme-init.scm` file somewhere somewhere on the Internet, create a `/usr/share/uim/lib/` directory and copy the `.scm` file there (along with whatever other files it comes with). But this seems hard, hacky and gross and I'm scared it might break something.

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Perhaps with `apt` or `dpkg`? Or maybe just reinstalling all of my `uim`-related libraries somehow?

## Other stuff I've tried

- `$ sudo apt upgrade -f` fails.
- `$ sudo apt reinstall <uim-something>` results in the same error.

Here's what happens when I run `dpkg --configure -a`

```
me@debian:~/writing/personal$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-xim:
 uim-xim depends on uim (>= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Version of uim on system is 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2.
 uim-xim depends on uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Package uim-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package uim-xim (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libuim-data (1:1.8.8-6) ...
Error: in load: file "/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm" not found
dpkg: error processing package libuim-data (--configure):
 installed libuim-data package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-qt5:
 uim-qt5 depends on uim (= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Version of uim on system is 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2.
 uim-qt5 depends on uim-qt5-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Package uim-qt5-immodule is not installed.
 uim-qt5 depends on uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Package uim-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package uim-qt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-gtk2.0:
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim (= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Version of uim on system is 1:1.8.6+gh20161003.0.d63dadd-2.
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim-gtk2.0-immodule (= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Package uim-gtk2.0-immodule is not installed.
 uim-gtk2.0 depends on uim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-6); however:
  Package uim-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package uim-gtk2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 uim-xim
 libuim-data
 uim-qt5
 uim-gtk2.0
```

Edit: Update: I ended up wiping the system so I can no longer test what does/doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade a stable system to testing or unstable? The output of `apt-cache policy` might help up recommend a solution, but it may also be some breakage expected outside "stable land".

Comment: I also had a `"/usr/share/uim/lib/sigscheme-init.scm" not found` error when trying to run [`surf` of suckless.org](https://surf.suckless.org). In the end, I had to `$ sudo apt autoremove uim` to solve this.

Comment: Download the missing package manually and install it manually. I would first try `apt download PACKAGE` and then `sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE`. If that doesn't work, you should be able to download the package manually via http/ftp from the repisitory **and/or** extract all files manually, but make sure you study the install-script of this package, if it has any, and do all the needed configurations by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removed all references to `uim` and `anthy`.

Then I ran:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

As described in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/7vscpw/issues_with_uim/)

Comment: had to remove them 2 times...

Answer (score 0):

First install/upgrade uim-common. (Correct version required by the packages as show ) If You do not get it with apt do it with dpkg and it's force options.

Comment: On buster (stable) this is not an option: `Package uim-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  uim-data uim libuim8 libuim-scm0 libuim-custom2

E: Package 'uim-common' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Yes this is true and the message tells You the details. The package was integrated into the meintioned uim packages. The file uim/sigscheme-init.scm the OP needed for libuim-data is now in uim-data. So if You need this file a dependency, install or update the uim-data. Otherwise to be able to give You a hint for Your case I would need some details on why You want to install uim-common. @sage

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/uim-anthy.prerm` file by commenting lines

```
if which uim-module-manager >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    uim-module-manager --unregister anthy-utf8 --path /var/lib/uim
fi
```

and execute `apt-get --fix-broken install`. The file content will be restored after fixing completes.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 11 (from Debian 10)

- su
- pico /var/lib/dpkg/status
- ctrl + W to search
- search for uim
- delete uim related packages from Package: to Description: (That is next Package: line
- ctrl + O
- ctrl + x
- apt --fix-broken install
- apt update
- apt upgrade
- apt dist-upgrade

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix the issue with UIM and its package dependencies. This puts the scm files in place and allows for ium-data to continue with installation.

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
cp /var/cache/apt/archives/uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-9_all.deb .
ar vx uim-data_1%3a1.8.8-9_all.deb
tar -xJvf data.tar.xz
sudo cp -irav usr/share/uim/* /usr/share/uim/
```

Once that was in place, I was able to continue with "apt --fix-broken install" and "apt upgrade".